# how to clear specific written content in terminal using zig-spoon

Tags: zig, tui

I'm trying to make a TUI menu that shows the selected option in green color and when you click on up or down it should clear **only** the written **text by application**, so basically only the text that was added after script was run should be deleted.

The problem is that while using `zig-spoon` library I couldn't find a way to clear a specific part, there are functions `term.cook()` and `term.uncook()` ( in `zig-spoon` ) which clear totally all the terminal and I didn't seem yet to find any solution how to prevent that.

I've tried to change a little bit source code of `zig-spoon`, I've noticed the following:
in file `Term.zig`, function `uncook()` if you change `spells.enter_alt_buffer` to `spells.leave_alt_buffer` - you already won't have cleared console by the start, however it will appear after another render

If I would also be able to change `spells.clear()` in `cook()` function into something that would clear the last X lines - that would also solve the problem

I would also accept as an answer an alternative library or another solution without using `zig-spoon`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Additional information:

My Zig version: 0.11.0
[Zig-spoon source code](https://github.com/efjimm/zig-spoon)